# Do APS journals allow PGF figures?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, journal-publishing, journal

I'm generating `.pgf` files using matplotlib, so they look neat in manuscripts compiled with pdflatex. I have them in separate files, and use via `\input{}` inside `figure` environments, in the main `.tex` file.

But I'd like to know if APS journals like the Physical Review series, or for that matter, any of the popular Physics journals accept this.

I ask because the say (https://journals.aps.org/prl/authors):

> Preferred formats are .ps, .eps, .pdf, .jpg, and .png

If they do accept it, will there be trouble in the HTML display of those figures on the websites of these journals?

p.s. I also have a TikZ figure.

Comment: You can try compiling your PGF and TikZ figures as standalone pdf files and use them with `\includegraphics`. With a bit of luck the output will be the same as when you directly use them with `\input` or inline code.

Comment: @Marijn Thanks! I will do that as the last resort.

Comment: I would ask APS about this, APS is after all the authority on what APS accepts ...

Answer (score 4):

I sent a mail to APS, and they replied with the same information available online:

> APS accepts figure files in .ps and .eps (preferred formats); also, .pdf, .png, or .jpg formats.
>   Kindly note all figures in the same format is encouraged; however, a combination of these is acceptable.

So what I'm finally doing is using the [standalone](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/standalone) document class to generate individual PDFs of each of my PGF and TikZ plots.

Comment: Looks like someone else had similar issues: https://bitbucket.org/martin_scharrer/standalone/issues/29/incompatible-with-revtex-41